# How to iterate through two lists in HTL/Sightly?

Tags: html, list, markup, sightly

I want to create a checklist, of which the title/text next to each checkbox comes from a name list, and a description of the title right below each corresponding checkbox and title comes from a value list.

The second list, the value list, would look something like this:

```
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Melon']
```

I have the checklist with titles next to it complete, but am confused how I can implement usage of a second list in HTL that will exist under every checkbox.

```
<div class="class1" data-sly-list.item="${model.titleList}"> 
        <ul>
            <li class="class2">
                <label class="class3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="${item.code}">
                        <span>${item.name}</span>
                </label>
          </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

I am still learning HTL, I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a model like:

```
use(function () {
    return {
        titleList: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape', 'Melon'],
        descriptionList: ["This is an apple", "This is an orange", "This is a grape"]
    };
});
```

Then you could just leverage `itemList.index` against the second list:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="logic.js"></sly>
<div class="class1" data-sly-list.item="${model.titleList}"> 
    <ul>
        <li class="class2">
            <label class="class3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="${item}">
                <span>${model.descriptionList[itemList.index]}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**However**, I do believe that a better approach is to have a proper model:

```
use(function () {
    return {
        items: [
            { title: "Apple", description: "This is an apple"},
            { title: "Orange", description: "This is an orange"},
            { title: "Grape", description: "This is a grape"},
            { title: "Melon", description: ""}]
    };
});
```

and render it without relying on weak coupling between lists:

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="logic.js"></sly>
<div class="class1" data-sly-list.item="${model.items}"> 
    <ul>
        <li class="class2">
            <label class="class3">
                <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="${item.title}">
                <span>${item.description}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```